# How to securely send private data over a web socket to an objective-c client and back to the server?

Tags: php, objective-c, sockets, cocoa

I am making a `wss://` connection to [ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/websocket) (a PHP socket library) using [SocketRocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket) (an Objective-c socket library).

I plan to send private data over this socket connection and then send the data back to the server with a `https://` request.

---

The objective-c code:

```
//initiate global variable
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray* keys;

...

//receive the private data with SocketRocket
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSString *)string
{
    [_keys insertObject:string];
}

...

//$_POST the file data with sthttp
STHTTPRequest *r = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:@"https://example.com/test.php"];
r.POSTDictionary = @{ @"key":_keys[0] };
...
```

---

Is there any possible way that a client can intercept this private data (within reason [buffer overflow, man in the middle, etc...])?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using wss:// and https:// protocols, you don't have to worry about a man in the middle attack since all the data being sent is encrypted anyway.

However if under any circumstance you have to send data over an insecure protocol or URL query string, you can encrypt the data yourself using PHP's open SSL module and send it in clear text (eg:$_GET params).

Example: 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php#91210

In this example `$crypttext` will be binary data. This can be encoded into a base64 string and the url encoded if you need to send it via a GET or POST request.

`urlencode(base64_encode($crypttext))`

On the receiving end you can base64 decode and url decode to get the binary information and then decrypt the data using the private key as shown in the example.

`base64_decode(urldecode($crypttext)`

Comment: Well encoding and decoding aren't necessarily encryption, they basically just render the text unreadable for human eye, but easily decoded. If the person is using regular https that should be fine

Comment: Actually the encoding it not for the encryption. If you look at my example I advise to encode the already encrypted data. This is because the encrypted data over open ssl  is in Binary format. So you will have to base46 encode it (to get it in String format) and the url encode it (to make it URL friendly) so that you can send the binary data over a POST or a GET (query string param) request.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that your certificates are all up to date and make sure your private key cert is protected and not accessible to anyone but you.

One note to remember is that if you are doing any logging, you might end up logging data that you want secure. I would double check your logging policy and make sure you are ok with it. Sometimes information will be passed along the url as query params and then those are logged to the servers log files.

If there is any history that you are saving, make sure to check that out or any caches on the mobile devices just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You will want to use TLS+ protocols with sha256+ encryption with secure ciphers.

Note: SSL+ protocol are insecure and can be subceptible to man-in-the-middle.
Note:
1. Be sure you create cert with sha256+ 
2. Have cert signed.
3. Configure Apache or web server to use SSL with TLS and Secure cipher suites.
4. Be sure each hosts trusts the other hosts's ssl. (If two way)

Sorry so general, but would need more info.

Regards,
Wesley